# Android changing background color when using an Adapter in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using the AlertDialog to show some debug info. I simply have a list that I drop info into. In an attempt to make it more readable I would like to change the background color of the individual items in the list, based on they type. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the color I want to hold. Here is the View of the adapter I am using:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    RuleDebugItem item = mData.get(position);

    tv.setSingleLine(false);
    if(item.type.equalsIgnoreCase(Field.VARIABLE)) {
        tv.setText(item.ruleDebugText);
        tv.setTextSize(18);
        v.setBackgroundColor(color.bluelight);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.white));
    }
    else if (item.type.equalsIgnoreCase(Field.FUNCTION)) {
        tv.setText(item.ruleDebugText);
        tv.setTextSize(16);
        v.setBackgroundColor(color.greenlight);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.white));
    }
    else if (item.type.equals("Condition")) {
        tv.setText("   " + item.ruleDebugText);
        tv.setTextSize(14);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.black));
    }
    return v;
}
```

I was expecting the `v.setBackgroundColor(color.greenlight);` to change the backround color. I suppose I could build out my own dialog and such, but I really didn't want to spend a lot of time on this since it is probably throwaway code.

thanks!

Comment: you can change this in onBindViewHolder method which can be easily managable

Comment: @Selvin As stated, throw away code and a work in progress. Condition (and other items) will be added in later. If already solved using an ArrayAdpater and AlertDialog please send me the link. thanks.

Comment: Rahul - ArrayAdapter does not seem to have a onBindViewHolder method. Or are suggesting I do something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was not quite what I was expecting. Turns out the AlertDialog was not accepting standard colors, rather it needed to have them from the Android Styles. Not sure if this was due to someone setting styles on our side (possible since I did not write the base code) or if that is the nature of AlertDialog. So if someone else encounters this, here is the final code (please note this is just throwaway debug code, it is not optimized):

```
public class RuleDebugItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RuleDebugItem> {
Context mContext; 
int mLayoutResourceId;    
ArrayList<RuleDebugItem> mData;

public RuleDebugItemAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<RuleDebugItem> data) {
    super(context, resource, data);
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutResourceId = resource;
    mData = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    RuleDebugItem item = mData.get(position);

    tv.setSingleLine(false);
    if (item.type.equalsIgnoreCase(Field.VARIABLE)) {
        tv.setText(item.ruleDebugText);
        tv.setTextSize(18);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.white));
        tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.black));
    }
    else if (item.type.equalsIgnoreCase(Field.FORMRULE)) { 
        tv.setText(item.ruleDebugText);
        tv.setTextSize(18);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.white));
        tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.black));
    }
    else if (item.type.equalsIgnoreCase(Field.FUNCTION)) {

        tv.setTextSize(16);
        if (item.success) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.holo_green_light));
            tv.setText(Field.SPACE + item.ruleDebugText);
        }
        else {
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));
            tv.setText("Init " + item.ruleDebugText);
        }

        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.white));
    }
    else if (item.type.equalsIgnoreCase(Field.ACTION)) {

        tv.setTextSize(16);
        if (item.success) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.holo_green_light));
            tv.setText(Field.SPACE + item.ruleDebugText);
        }
        else {
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));
            tv.setText("Pre-" + item.ruleDebugText);
        }

        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.white));
    }
    else if (item.type.equals(Field.CONDITION)) {
        tv.setText(item.ruleDebugText);
        tv.setTextSize(16);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        if (item.success)
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.holo_green_light));
        else 
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.holo_red_light));
        tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.white));
    }
    return v;
} 
}
```